# Howto get user information from a selfhosting webserver usering owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

I created a selfhosting webapp  (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin) as recommended in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60988876/self-hosting-https-endpoints-in-net-core-app-without-using-asp-net) by @Anouar.

It works as expected. But I can't get user information from the context. There doesn't seem to be any Claim in HttpContext.Users.Claims (nrOfClaims = 0).

```
public class SayHi : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("sayhi/{name}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string name)
    {
        var userId = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        var nrOfClaims = HttpContext.User.Claims.Count();
```

Is it possible to get the username and the user-domainname via HttpContext here?

I searched various sites. I tried IHttpContextAccessor [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core) via constructor dependency injection. But the HttpContextAccessor seems to be the same as HttpContext itself.

Comment: What authentication mechanism are you using

Comment: There is no authentification. I will use it as a local webserver in a windows service. Is it in principle possible to get the local username and domainname of the user, who sends a get or post request without authentication?

Comment: You have to enable windows authentication to get that information

Comment: So if i understood that correctly, without any additional authentication i.e. user logs in in some way, i can't get the doman and username of the user who sent a get or a post from a browser in the httpcontext?