# How to port <system.serviceModel> configurations when converting WCF app from .Net framework to .Net Core?

Tags: wcf, .net-core

I have an existing app under .Net framework 4.6.2. The app includes a WCF client and a server, both hosted in IIS. Now I am planning to port the app to .Net Core and the first challenge I am facing is to figure out how to port my WCF configurations. We have endpoints and bindings configured in the <system.serviceModel> section of the web.config files on both client and server side. For instance, here is part of our server side config:
[image]

And here is the client side

[image]

Now under .Net Core, the <system.serviceModel> doesn't seem to be supported any more. If so, where does it moved to? What's the best approach of converting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to migrate wcf from .net framework to .net core. This is impossible because many libraries are used and they do not support .net core.But you can realize the function of wcf through other methods on .net core, you can refer to [What replaces WCF in .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522849/what-replaces-wcf-in-net-core).

Comment: Thanks Theobald. I am new to .Net Core but I heard that you can still use WCF under .Net Core, even though there are only a few bindings are supported, such as HTTP and NetTcp,etc. Isn't that true?

Comment: Did a bit research and found this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/why-migrate-wcf-to-dotnet-grpc?view=aspnetcore-3.1). It says ".NET Core and .NET 5 support calling WCF services but won't offer server-side support for hosting WCF.". So, you are right, I am out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post, but there is now a CoreWCF library through which you can do server-side hosting with WCF in .NET core:
https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF

Using this library you can easily upgrade your old .net framework WCF projects into .Net Core.