# System.ServiceModel error Operation not supported when consuming WCF embedded in Windows Service in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-services

I have to redesign an application. The application was originally built in ASP.NET MVC Razor views with jQuery and consumed WCF embedded in Windows service at backend. I have to redesign the application in ASP.Net Core API with Angular 8. I have to use the same WCF services in my application I cannot change that. The original code was use System.ServiceModel library to initialize WCF endpoints which is working in the original application. But same code is giving me an error in ASP.Net Core API. This is the original code.

```
    public CleanupChannelFactory(string endpointConfigurationName, bool callInitializeEndpoint)
        : base(typeof(TServiceContract))
    {
        if (callInitializeEndpoint)
            InitializeEndpoint(endpointConfigurationName, null);
    }
```

I'm getting the error on InitializeEndpoint(endpointConfigurationName, null). The endpointConfigurationName contains the endpoint of the name of WCF Service. I've searched for a few options and found out that WCF consumption is not supported in ASP.Net Core API. Is there any workaround to this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the wcf service is greatly restricted in .netcore. This is the [wcf feature supported in .netcore](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/main/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md), and then this is a [replacement for wcf in .netcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522849/what-replaces-wcf-in-net-core).