# WCF replacement in. Net Core

Tags: wcf, .net-core, windows-authentication, .net-5

I need to create client application and server service application, that uses Remote Procedure Calls with windows authentification and impersonation.
Since WCF is not supported in Net Core and gRPC uses http/2, which not supppoted by Windows Authentification are there any alternatives I could use for that?

Answer (score 2):

WCF is a Windows-only framework, while.net Core is cross-platform.

The links below contain some usage and examples that you can refer to.[What replaces WCF in .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522849/what-replaces-wcf-in-net-core)

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the link, but I saw it already and I did not find any information about any net core library with which I could use RPC with Windows Authentification and impersonation on WinForms

Answer (score 0):

I have found the ServiceWire package to be an excellent replacement for NamedPipes and WCF, especially if you do not need to queue requests or share objects.

Answer (score 0):

While more modern approaches would be preferred, if you already have heavy WCF dependencies or WCF knowledge, you can look into [CoreWCF](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrading-a-wcf-service-to-dotnet-6/#:%7E:text=About%20Corewcf).